# Assemble function of IDA Pro not working properly

Tags: ida, patching

I am using the Patch Program option of IDA Pro to edit the assembly of a binary at runtime.

When I enter the following instruction:

```
mov rax, [rsp + 0x48]
```

I get an "Invalid operand" error from IDA Pro. I tried changing the above instruction to different variants as shown below:

```
mov rax, [rsp + 48h]
mov rax, [rsp + 48]
```

However, it still gives me an error.

This is a valid assembly instruction. I can edit the assembly in other softwares like x64_dbg and it works with the above disassembly.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294095/ida-invalid-operand-error-when-patching The support is very little. Try https://github.com/keystone-engine/keypatch/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md

Comment: Okay, I will try using the KeyStone engine. It's surprising that they do not plan to enhance the Assembler feature in IDA Pro even though they provide it as a feature.

Comment: The other workaround is of course to use another debugger like Olly Debugger or x64_dbg, get the opcodes and then use the Patch Program feature of IDA Pro.